# What is the best practise: hiding elements in React

Tags: reactjs

We have some modals in our app and I am curious what is the best practise here to hide them. We use 3rd party component which has field `isOpen`, but we also have some additional data in wrapping component. This data is needed just for modal.

So, is it better to:

1. not even render wrapping component which is hidden

`{this.state.showModal && CreateModal}`

or

2. always render this component and control it visibility through

`<Modal isOpen={this.props.showModal}`

Answer (score 0):

The 1st one always work, the 2nd one only works when the view has an `isOpen` prop(which is not always the case). As long as it works, both are good and no apparent advantages of one over the other.

Note that 2nd one, auto update of the visibility is not supported, since `this.props.showModal` is NOT `this.state.showModal`. You **cannot control** its visibility once the component is instantiated.

Comment: I am using specifing componen, let's call it `Modal`, which has `isOpen`, but I also use my component which wraps `Modal`, let's call it `ModalWrapper` There is another component `Layout` which has the information in state. So `Layout > ModalWrapper > Modal`. The thing is that `ModalWrapper` is connected to redux and can be and also is updated very often. Therefore I consider 1st variant as better.

Comment: Agreed that would be great.